# stackexchange.com does not remember last visited page when logging in

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com

Select [Edit](/#edit-interesting) anchor next to **Favorite Tags** in the sidebar. ----------------------------------->

Now select [advanced tag subscriptions »](https://stackexchange.com/filters).

If you have not logged in on stackexchange, clicking this link will redirect to the login page; once logged in, navigating to [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) rather than https://stackexchange.com/filters

[image]

Comment: @ivarni you can report bugs anywhere.

Comment: To reproduce: go to stackexchange.com, delete the `acct` cookie (the  session cookie), then go back to meta.stackoverflow.com and follow the steps above.